# Get most common data from CSV File with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I'm making a project for my work, and there is a big problem...
I'm making a software that takes information about users from a CSV(coma separate values) file. Every user has own phone number and a number that he was called. When the inforamtion is gathered from the file, i want to take the all phone numbers that are for a number and sort them ascending. I want not to be all ocurance of phone number, just this that are with big duration to be up. That means like that:

1-345345-9375683027
2-345345-3070982743
3-345345-9375683027
4-345345-3070982743
5-345345-9375683027
6-345345-2389479734
7-345345-2349875993

Number 1, 3 and 5 are equals.
Number 2 and 4 are equals.
I want to sort the number like this:

1-345345-9375683027
2-345345-3070982743
3-345345-2389479734
4-345345-2349875993

Now 1 us the most common, 2 is less comon that first and so one...
I was trying any thing but without problem.
Like this one:

```
var result = user.transactions.where(x=>x.phone == user.phone);
```

If you want to look at the project that i'm making here is the solution file:
http://mtelanalyzer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the phone numbers are a `List<String>`:

```
var result = phoneNumbers.GroupBy(pn => pn)
             .Select(grp => new { Number = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() })
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
             .Select(x => x.Number);
```

1. group by phone-number
2. select an anonymous type to be able to order by the count
3. order by descending(highest occurence first)<strike>, then by the number</strike>
4. select the number, the result is an `IEnumerable<String>` (or whatever type it is)

<strike>**Edit**: I've only just seen that you're ordering as second not by number but by the index. That makes it a little bit more complicated:</strike>

```
var result = phoneNumbers.Select((pn, i) => new { Number = pn, Index = i })
             .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
             .Select(grp => new { 
                 Number = grp.Key, 
                 Count  = grp.Count(), 
                 Index  = grp.First().Index 
             })
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
             .ThenBy(x => x.Index)
             .Select(x => x.Number);
```

Comment: It is realy good code, thank you againg. It is universal, can be used anywhere. This helps me in many moments about now.